# Como dispensar o teclado ao pressionar o botão de voltar do celular em flutter

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Estou usando um TextField na minha tela e já implementei o GestureDetector para tirar o foco do campo quando o usuário clicar em qualquer lugar fora dele:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold...
```

Essa parte funciona, consigo tirar o foco do campo e, rodando como um app debug o teclado é dispensado normalmente. Mas ao rodar o aplicativo no browser do celular o teclado é dispensado e, logo em seguida, volta a ficar ativo. Pra reproduzir isso basta buildar o aplicativo pra web, clicar no campo de texto e apertar o botão de voltar do dispositivo mobile

aqui o código mínimo:

```
    class ProdutoDetalhePage extends StatefulWidget {
  

      const ProdutoDetalhePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<ProdutoDetalhePage> createState() => _ProdutoDetalhePageState();
    }
    
    class _ProdutoDetalhePageState extends State<ProdutoDetalhePage> {
      final TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        textController.addListener(() {});
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        textController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return GestureDetector(
           onTap: () {
             FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
               if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                 currentFocus.unfocus();
               }
             },
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                    child: TextField(
                        maxLength: 100,
                        maxLines: 3,
                        controller: textController,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
      );
}
```

Comment: da uma olhada nesta URL: https://flutterigniter.com/dismiss-keyboard-form-lose-focus/

Comment: @JasarOrion foi essa solução que eu tentei. Ela resolve o problema no app, mas não no browser

Comment: me desculpe vou checar aqui a documentação .

Comment: tenta isso aqui estou usando em um projetinho: 
`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');`

Comment: Eu coloco essa linha de código no onTap?

Comment: sim o import vc taca no inicio do arquivo da classe em questao e vc invoca este metodo no ontap. da uma buscada no google pra saber mais como ele funciona mas em um projeto q uso o flutter no navegador e no desktop com teclado virtual eu uso esse metodo.

Comment: Tentei aqui e não deu. Pelo o que eu entendi esse método é pra dispensar ao clicar fora da área de texto também, certo? Só que o meu problema é dispensar o teclado ao usar o botão de voltar do dispositivo, então ele não entra no onTap nesse cenário

Comment: aqui ele esta dentro do onTap event

Comment: Você quer que ao clicar no botão de voltar o teclado suma, ao invés de fechar a tela? Tanto no botão fisico do celular quanto no que fica na status bar?

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem sua dúvida é relacionada a ação de voltar, no caso o que você precisa é utilizar o *Widget* [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) [EN].

Com ele você consegue ficar "ouvindo" a ação que é disparada para fazer o *popBack*, tanto pelo botão voltar físico do dispositivo, quanto pelo botão da sua *statusBar*.

```
class ProdutoDetalhePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProdutoDetalhePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProdutoDetalhePage> createState() => _ProdutoDetalhePageState();
}

class _ProdutoDetalhePageState extends State<ProdutoDetalhePage> {
  final TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
  final textNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    textController.addListener(() {});
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // WillPopScope fica escutando a ação de "voltar" e executa o que está dentro da função.
    // Espera um retorno TRUE(Fecha a tela) ou FALSE(Mantem a tela aberta).
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (textNode.hasPrimaryFocus || MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0) {
          // Seta o foco para um focusNode fantasma, tirando assim o foco do componente que deseja
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: textNode,
            maxLength: 100,
            maxLines: 3,
            controller: textController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Explicação

A validação abaixo é o seguinte:

```
        if (textNode.hasPrimaryFocus || MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0) {
          // Seta o foco para um focusNode fantasma, tirando assim o foco do componente que deseja
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
```

Caso seu campo de texto possua o foco principal ou o `viewInsets.bottom` for maior que zero (Foi o que encontrei para saber se o teclado está aberto) vai mandar o foco para um "Node fantasma" e retorna FALSE para não fechar a tela, caso o teclado esteja fechado, a tela será fechada.

**ATENÇÃO:** Não testei em um device físico, então pode ser necessário algum pequeno ajuste.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas infelizmente não deu certo. Eu tentei aqui mas o resultado foi o mesmo